# java do while loop keeps repeating and I can't figure out why

Tags: java, do-while

So I've attached a debugger, and tried different inputs and I can't seem to figure out why this won't get past the loop. When ran I enter "l" or "L", then entry gets set to that, then input is set to the capitalized version and then it repeats.

```
public static char displayMenu(){
    char input;
    sc.nextLine();//clear junk
    do {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t\t Enter L to (L)oad ");
        String entry = sc.nextLine();
        input = entry.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    } while (input != 'L' || input!='M' || input != 'P' || input != 'Q');
```

Comment: Have to try to print input? Is its value correct?

Comment: the condition will always evaluate to true. perhaps you want to use `&&`

Comment: Yeah input comes out with L when I input lowercase l right before it is tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `boolean` `||` is incorrect. If a value is `L` it is then not `M`, `P` or `Q` so your loop will continue to iterate. I think you wanted something like,

```
while (input != 'L' && input != 'M' && input != 'P' && input != 'Q');
```

or

```
while (!(input == 'L' || input == 'M' || input == 'P' || input == 'Q'));
```

consider when `input` is `L`, clearly `L` is not `M` and so your initial `while` condition would continue to iterate.

Answer (score 2):

`input` will only have one value. That value cannot be both `L` and `M`. You need to change the termination condition.

Answer (score 1):

your have used logical or condition it needs just one true statement to run, even though you enter 'L' , at this point your one statement is false but other statements became true that why it keeps on repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char input;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);//clear junk
    do {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t\t Enter L to (L)oad ");
        String entry = sc.nextLine();
        input = entry.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    } while (input != 'L' && input!='M' && input != 'P' && input != 'Q');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char displayMenu(){
    char input;
    sc.nextLine();//clear junk
    do {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t\t Enter L to (L)oad ");
        String entry = sc.nextLine();
        input = entry.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    } while ((input != 'L') && (input!='M') && (input != 'P') && (input != 'Q'));
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

[De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) tell us that

`(input != 'L' || input!='M' || input != 'P' || input != 'Q')`

is the same as

`! (input == 'L' && input=='M' && input == 'P' && input == 'Q')`

which must always be true because

`(input == 'L' && input=='M' && input == 'P' && input == 'Q')`

must always be false because

`input` can only be equal to one thing at a time.

Use De Morgan's laws to avoid extra NOT's when you can.  Computers don't care but humans don't process NOT's very well.